# Wordpress Trying to use get_title() in loop array as the category name

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

On my wordpress page template Im trying to use the get_title() in my arguments array for the a loop but i cant get it to return any posts.

This is where im up to;

```
<?php 
            $args = array( 
                      'category_name' => 'the_title();'
                   );

            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="entry"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Im unable to get any posts to return on this page unless i manually  enter the slug for the category i want to use which is not ideal as the page slug will always be the same as the post category slug.

My logic behind this is that i dont want to have an individual page templeate for each page with the different cat as i will end up with hundreds of page  templetes.

Any help appreciated 
Cheers
Jon

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked a treat, i had to add                                           $args = array( 
                'cat' => '$cat',
                'category__not_in' => '1',

                );                                                                                                                to exlude the uncatogorized posts. also could anyone explain what "global $cat" is doing?  thanks again for your help!

Comment: Looks like i spoke too soon, for some reason it is only loading 6 out of the 8 posts in the category. also the category__not_in i added make it pull a single post from another category. i beleive i need the slug rather that the id to make this work?

Comment: `global $cat;`  gives you ID of the current category when you're on category archive page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `the_title();` as a string do to `' '`. Also, `the_title()` gets title of the object in the loop, not of a category.
You can do the following:

```
 global $post; 
 $args = array('category_name' => $post->post_name);
```

Comment: Looks like i spoke too soon, for some reason it is only loading 6 out of the 8 posts in the category. also the category__not_in i added make it pull a single post from another category. i beleive i need the slug rather that the id to make this work?

Comment: @Jonnygogo no, for `cat` it is ID. `category__not_in ` is also ID and I'm not sure why you'd want it here. `cat` will already include posts only from the curret category. Try adding `'posts_per_page' => 10` (or any other number) to array of args.

Comment: Ive added the posts per page and basicly whats happening is the query is now displaying all of the posts i have. Its just luck that the first posts that are shown are correct for the page im testing on. My original idea was to have the page title slug the same as the category slug so i could use the page name in the query. does this make sense?

Comment: Oh, you could try  `global $post;  $args = array('category_name' => $post->post_name);`

Comment: That perfect, did the trick! thank you very much for you help :)

Comment: @Jonnygogo you're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You have passed `the_title();` as a string, so will be treated as string, not a function, so it will not return title. You can use global variable `$cat`, So your code will be,

```
<?php
global $cat;
$args = array('cat' => $cat);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="entry"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Great, please consider my answer to upvote and accept it.

Comment: Looks like i spoke too soon, for some reason it is only loading 6 out of the 8 posts in the category. also the category__not_in i added make it pull a single post from another category. i beleive i need the slug rather that the id to make this work?